# Tagging a file to multiple folders in Google Drive Android mobile app

Tags: google-drive

With the web interface on Google Drive, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click can place a file or folder into several folders. But with the mobile app on Android, this feature seems to be missing. I tried a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> move but to no avail. Even worse when the file has been in several folders before that structure is lost.

Does anyone have any idea how to move a file into multiple folders using the Android app?